# JsonServiceClient not respecting RedirectHttpHandler response

Tags: c#, typescript, servicestack

We have a global handler setup for catching a specific type of exception. It is possibly thrown from multiple service endpoints using a base service implementation. We bind the error handlers and try redirect using a RedirectHttpHandler:

```
ServiceExceptionHandlers.Add(HandledErrorLogging);
...

 private object HandledErrorLogging(IRequest httpreq, object request, Exception ex)
{

    if (ex is NoActiveSubscriptionException)
    {
        return new RedirectHttpHandler
        {
            RelativeUrl = "/account?error=",
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect
        };
    }
}
```

We are using JsonServiceClient to query these endpoints.

The JsonServiceClient is not respecting the RedirectHttpHandler redirect. When we connect jsonclient.responsefilter(r), r.redirectedicted is false:

```
  let client = new JsonServiceClient(process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL);
  client.setBearerToken(cookie.load("XSRF-TOKEN"));
  JsonServiceClient.globalResponseFilter = function(e)
  {
    console.log("e.redirect:", e.redirected));
  };
  return client;
}
```

What is the best way to cause a redirect using the ServiceExceptionHandlers and the JsonServiceClient ?

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectHttpHandler` is an `IHttpAsyncHandler`, it can only be used at the [start of the request pipeline](https://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations) in `RawHttpHandlers` which is used to tell ServiceStack which HttpHandler it should use to handle the request.

`ServiceExceptionHandlers` is used to [override handling of an Exception](https://docs.servicestack.net/api-design#overriding-the-default-exception-handling) which you can override to return a different error Response DTO.

If nothing has been written to the Response you can return a redirect response with `HttpResult.Redirect()`.